# NoSuchElementException while Iterating

Tags: java, android, iterator, iteration

I have been struck with `Iterator` for past few hours.

While I execute *Iterator*, am getting **NoSuchElementException**

**Code**

```
    new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");

            final HashSet<String> mList = new HashSet<String>();
            for (SomeList sList : refList) { // <-- 72 Items
                if (sList.isTrue()) {
                    mList.add(sList.getName());
                }
            }
            System.out.println("wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww");

            System.out.println("sList " + sList.size()); // <-- 3 Items

            final Iterator<String> iterator = mList.iterator();
            while (iterator.hasNext()) { // Check if has next element
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        System.out.println("zzzzzzzzzzzzzz");
                        System.out.println("\n-------------------- " + (String) iterator.next()); //move to next element
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }.start();
```

**Logcat**

```
    D/dalvikvm(25527): start new thread
    D/dalvikvm(25527): threadid=13: notify debugger
    D/dalvikvm(25527): threadid=13 (Thread-4167): calling run()
    I/System.out(25527): xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    I/System.out(25527): wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww
    I/System.out(25527): mList 3 <-- Size of List
    I/System.out(25527): yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
    I/System.out(25527): yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy

    // Prints around 80 times removed for better readability

    I/System.out(25527): yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
    I/System.out(25527): yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
    I/System.out(25527): zzzzzzzzzzzzzz
    I/System.out(25527): -------------------- abc <-- data 1
    I/System.out(25527): yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
    I/System.out(25527): zzzzzzzzzzzzzz
    I/System.out(25527): -------------------- efg <-- data 2
    I/System.out(25527): zzzzzzzzzzzzzz
    I/System.out(25527): -------------------- hij <-- data 3
    I/System.out(25527): zzzzzzzzzzzzzz
    D/AndroidRuntime(25527): Shutting down VM
    W/dalvikvm(25527): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41c5c9a8)
    D/dalvikvm(25527): threadid=13: exiting
    D/dalvikvm(25527): threadid=13: bye!
    E/AndroidRuntime(25527): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    E/AndroidRuntime(25527): java.util.NoSuchElementException
    E/AndroidRuntime(25527):    at java.util.HashMap$HashIterator.nextEntry(HashMap.java:794)
    E/AndroidRuntime(25527):    at java.util.HashMap$KeyIterator.next(HashMap.java:819)
    E/AndroidRuntime(25527):    at xxx.xxx.xxxxxx.models.YYYYY$1$1.run(YYYYY.java:62)  <-- Here is the exception.
    E/AndroidRuntime(25527):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
    E/AndroidRuntime(25527):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    E/AndroidRuntime(25527):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
    E/AndroidRuntime(25527):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)
    E/AndroidRuntime(25527):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    E/AndroidRuntime(25527):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    E/AndroidRuntime(25527):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
    E/AndroidRuntime(25527):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
    E/AndroidRuntime(25527):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

---

**Line 62 in my code is**

> System.out.println("\n-------------------- " + (String) iterator.next());

Before posting this question I searched for [NoSuchElementException, Iterator](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=NoSuchElementException%20Iterator), tried most of the results but did not succeed.

Comment: can't do that. hasNext and next are not called on the same thread, meaning that `hasNext` will return true because `next` was not called yet.

Comment: use `final String value = iterator.next();` before calling `runOnUiThread`

Comment: @njzk2 That solved, but [You have put me in this Situation :)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/) I will accept your solution, if you can post as answer. stating the issue. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a concurrency issue here:

```
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            (String) iterator.next();
        }
    });
}
```

Because `hasNext` and `next` are not called on the same thread, you cannot be guaranteed that there will actually be a next when you call `next()`.

The loop will run several times without the iterator being advanced, resulting in more creation of `Runnable`s than items in the iterator, which in turn results in `next` being called more times than should be.

You can solve it using the following:

```
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    final String nextValue = (String) iterator.next();
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Do stuff with nextValue
        }
    });
}
```

which calls `hasNext` and `next` in the same thread, making sure each `hasNext` is immediately matched by a call to `next`